# How do you prevent Flask from logging specific routes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Currently I have a web server that has a number of API's, but am having an issue when it comes to reading logs as there is an API that is being hit every 5 minutes.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 11:20:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 11:25:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 11:30:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The API currently looks like this:

```
@app.route('/api-name', methods=['POST'])
def api_name():
```

Is there a way that I could pass an option so that when this API is called it doesn't log out?

Comment: Are you currently relying on the logs being printed on the terminal or are you referring a proper log file?

Comment: I am currently relying on what is being written to the terminal window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask block specific endpoints from logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000942/flask-block-specific-endpoints-from-logging)

Answer (score 0):

An ideal approach could be using [Flask's built-in wrapper](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/#logging) around Python's logging library and manually log whatever you in the respective routes.

A simple excerpt from Flask documentation:

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    user = get_user(request.form['username'])

    if user.check_password(request.form['password']):
        login_user(user)
        app.logger.info('%s logged in successfully', user.username)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        app.logger.info('%s failed to log in', user.username)
        abort(401)
```

What you could do is have different logs for different purposes. For access related logs, similar to what you see on the terminal where the following data is shown:
`{request_ip} - - {timestamp} "{request_method} {route} {http_version}" {response_status} -`

and a different log file with logging for your core application logic.

It's not a good idea to rely on the logs being spewed out on the terminal.